# Outlook Addin Error: Not loaded. A runtime error occurred during loading of COM add-in

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I have created an VSTO Outlook addin. The configuration is as follows:

- Visual Studio 2008
- Office 2007 Outlook add in (3.5 Framework)
- MSI created using Visual Studio Setup Project
- Deployed to Office 2010 under windows 7

It works fine on the Dev PC however it fails to load once installed on the test machine. The outlook addin window shows a `"Not loaded. A runtime error occurred during loading of COM add-in"`

It is my understanding that I should not need to install any PIA as the Office 2007 PIA are part of Office 2010.

So far I have tried the following:

- set `VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS` however it does not show any messages when it tries to start.
- configured `Fuslogvw.exe` (Assembly Binding Log Viewer) however it is not showing any binding errors.
- set `VTSO_LOGALERTS` and it is logging all alerts however as none are shown this has not helped.

Is there anything I am doing wrong or need to do in addition to make this work?

Comment: what version of vsto is installed on test machine?

Comment: For what I had read it had intially suggested that 2010 comes with VSTO 3.0 installed. I had tried to install the 3.0 runtime however this would not install. I am goign to try the 2010 runtime http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20479   as suggested by http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx

Comment: think VSTO 2010 RT is required for office 2010 addins

Comment: Installing the 2010 runtime did not help make any difference.

Comment: Are you sure the error isn't from the addin itself (like an unmanaged exception at startup) I have for ex, an addin that get disabled by office because of a timeout on an SqlConnection...

Comment: @BrijeshMishra - VSTOR 2010 RT is required for Visual Studion 2010, not Office 2010.

Comment: @John - what url did you use when you tried to install VSTOR30?  I have a Win7 with Office 2010 installed.  It had no problem installing VSTOR30.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23656

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you have the [VSTO 3.0 Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23656) installed on the test machine.

You will also need to install the [VSTO 3.0 Runtime Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1132) if you are running Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1.

[VSTO 4.0 Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20479) is not required in your situation because it is used with add-ins created with Visual Studio 2010.  Please note that the version of VSTO and runtime generally must agree with the version of Visual Studio used to create the add-in.

Comment: This requires 0ffice 2007 to be installed - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23656

Comment: Yes, just checked.  The VSTOR30 (Visual Studio Tools For Office Runtime) is needed because you built an Office 2007 add-in, even though you are running it on Office 2010.

Comment: @John, by the way, I've developed an Outlook 2007 add-in which I run on both Outlook 2010 and Outlook 2007.  VSTOR30 is required on both, and Outlook won't get to even the first line of code in your add-in without it.  Make sure your test machine has the Pre-reqs for the VSTO Redist, namely .NET Fx 3.5.

Comment: @John, also, if you are using VStudio 2008 SP1, then you need to be using VSTOR30 SP1 and .NET Fx 3.5 SP1.  Makes for a painful install process, but that appears to be what MS requires.

Comment: It works, thank you for your help. Turns out VSTO 3 need to be installed and then SPK1 after it.

Comment: Will this help in case of Office 2013? In one of my machines, with office 2013, the add in is not getting loaded...

Answer (score 0):

ere are a couple of usefull sites (I'm not going to copy and paste their advice on troubleshooting)
http://www.ceptara.com/node/183

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2008/04/22/troubleshooting-com-add-in-load-failures.aspx